# How would you create a non localized variable in a function so that it is accessible by other functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a variable in a `function` that I want to be accessible by other functions. How would you do that?

Comment: You don't. You do it properly, by passing parameters and avoiding globals.

Comment: delnan means that global variables (those added to the window object) that have the same name as local variables (those that are declared inside of a function) are potentially accessed instead of the local variable. The suggestion is that you avoid this.

Comment: Not only that. The whole "Global variables are evil" thingy is old and a plenthora of reasons have been given, many of which are reasonable. You can ask e.g. google, the SO search, or any decent programmer (where "decent" also means "knows why he follows dogma x"), among many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the object the property (variable) is added to (variables are always properties of some object).

If you want this new variable to be accessible to everything, then you add it to the window object, like this:

```
window.variablename = 'some value';
```

Comment: ah.. i see. so when you declare the variable for the first time you would do that?

Comment: If you *really* need global state, then define a global namespace instead of cluttering the window object.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe like this:

```
function funcA() {
    if(typeof funcA.variable == 'undefined') {
        funcA.variable = 0;
    }
    else {
        funcA.variable++;
    }
}

function funcB() {
  alert(funcA.variable);
}

funcA();
funcB(); //alerts 0
funcA();
funcA();
funcA();
funcB(); //alerts 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    var a;

    setA(1);
    alert(getA()); // 1

    function setA(value) {
        a = value;
    };

    function getA() {
        return a;
    }
})();
```

Comment: This is no different than `window.a = 1` or just using non declared global variables.

Answer (score 0):

please avoid global variables. if you have asynchronous calls via jquery, the usage of global variables may lead up to ambiguous behaviors.